# Tshark how to decode rtp.pt

Tags: wireshark, tshark

Could someone please help me on such topic.

Trying to decode a network flow using tshark via:

```
tshark -r somefile.pcap -d rtp.pt==96,rtpeven
```

This results to a:

> tshark: Protocol "rtpevent" isn't valid for layer type "rtp.pt"
>
> tshark: Valid protocols for layer type "rtp.pt" are: (empty)

Tried running on an old 1.12.7 wireshark version, and everything works file(has a wideload of available protocols).

Thanks.

Comment: It seems to work with 2.0.12 but fails with 2.4.0.  I would recommend filing a bug report: https://bugs.wireshark.org/bugzilla/.

Comment: Tried from 2.2 to 2.4, but didn't go as far as 2.0. Yes, solved this. Thanks